# TestFlight: Possible errors with multiple device types

Tags: ios, ipad, testflight, ipad-mini

I am currently developing an app for the iPad Air/Air 2. Is it possible to test it on iPad Mini 3 via TestFlight? Since I cannot check for myself at the moment, I'll be glad if you tell me some possible problems with this.

Best regards,
Boyan

Comment: I think you just install Testflight on iPad mini 3 to test. A problem that I met is memory, iPad mini 3 memory seems not good like iPad Air, so we maybe meet issues with UIImagePicker or something related to memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you:

Compatibility of TestFlight: [Please refer here](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8)

But On iPad Air tapping on test flight icon opens the app, but I get the dialog box "TestFlight Unavailable", TestFlight us currently unavailable. Try again later."
On my  3rd Genration iPad test flight is working normally.[More details](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5207)